# On the boundedness of linear representations of formal power series of languages.

Tags: formal-languages, linear-algebra

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite non-empty set of symbols (i.e. an alphabet). Fix $\pi, \eta\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$ and for every $\sigma\in\Sigma $ fix $A(\sigma)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.
We also require that for every $1 \leq i,j\leq m$ $\pi_i, \eta_i, (A(\sigma))_{i,j} \geq 0$ but $\pi,\eta,A(\sigma)\neq 0$.

If $w:=w_1\cdots w_n\in\Sigma^*$ let $A(w) := \prod_{i=1}^{n} A(w_i)$. 
Suppose that there exists a real $K$ such that for every $w\in\Sigma^*$ one has $|\pi A(w)\eta^{t} |\leq K$.

Is it true that this imply the existence of $K'$ such that for every $w\in\Sigma^*$ $||\pi A(w)||\leq K'$ for some $K'$? If not, any counterexample?

Here $||\cdot||$ denotes the usual $\ell_2$ norm of a real vector.

Comment: Is $\eta$ fixed?  If $\eta$ is 0 you can't say anything.  If $\eta| is strictly positive things look better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. We fix $\eta, \pi$ and $A(\sigma)$ but we rule out the case $\eta=0$. I've edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: I also guess there should be a counter-example with some η not strictly-positive and that the theorem might be true adding η>0 to hypothesis. Any hint or ref on this will be of great help. Thank you. 

Comment: As stated nothing works.  Just choose matrices whose rows are orthogonal to $\eta$.  Maybe you might want strictly positive matrices and vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Suppose that $A(\sigma)$ is upper
triangular with a $1$ in upper left position, and that
$\eta=[1\ 0\ 0\ \cdots\ 0]$ and $\pi=[1\ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1]$.
Note that $A(w)$ is also upper triangular with a $1$ at
upper left, and that $A(w)\eta^t=[1\ 0\ 0\ \cdots\ 0]^t$ and
so $\pi A(w)\eta^t=1$ for all $w$. But meanwhile, it is
easy to arrange that $\pi A(w)$ can become unboundedly
large by taking $w$ large.

For a concrete example, use $A(\sigma)=[1\ 1;\ 0\ 1]$ and
$\eta=[1\ 0]$ and $\pi=[1\ 1]$.

Comment: This is an answer to the original question; it doesn't answer the strictly-positive version of the question. (So it would be fine, Recursive, to de-accept it, in the hope of getting an answer to the edited question.)

Comment: Ok I've re-edited, now the statement should be ok with my intended interpretation of the problem. Your counterexample answer my question. Thank you!